# Ruby on Rails "Template is missing" Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting the following error:

> Template is missing
>
> Missing template admin/settings with {:formats=>[:html],
>   :locale=>[:en, :en], :handlers=>[:rxml, :erb, :builder, :rjs, :rhtml]}
>   in view paths "C:/Users/Me/Desktop/Application/app/views"

But everything seems to be in place.  I made sure the properties allow everyone full access to that file for troubleshooting, still a no go.  What am I missing here?

[image]

Ruby 1.8.7 Rails 3.0.3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The name of your template file should be "settings.html.erb". You're missing an "e" in the file extension.

Note the part of the error where it says `:handlers=>[:rxml, :erb, :builder, :rjs, :rhtml]`. The file extension of your view must be one of these for the template to be processed.

Comment: thank you, i don't why that happened. when i made my first attempt in creating a hello, world in RoR, this did not happen. but anyway, thanks.